# How to get only the alphanumeric characters that are before any special characters in a string?

Tags: python, regex, string

Example:

```
string1 = '71B46>TC>77'
```

Is there a way to get the following without having a for loop:

```
output = '71B46'
```

I can't hardcode ">" because special characters vary.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Comment: Another version is just `output = re.sub('\W.*', '', string1)`, there are many ways to skin a regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
text = "71B46>TC>77"
position = text.index('>')
result = text[0:position]
# 71B46
```

## Update

```
import re

regex = r"[\W+]"
text = "71B46>TC>77"
position = re.search(regex, text).start()
print(text[0:position])
# 71B46
```

Comment: I can't hardcode ">" because special characters vary.

Comment: Or `re.sub(r"[\W+]",'',s)`

Answer (score 0):

You should try this.

```
import re
start_pos = re.search(r'\W+', string1).start()
print(string1[0:start_pos])
```

Comment: Hi, it gave an error: sub() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'

Answer (score 0):

Without using regular expressions. Filter for characters that are alphanumeric.

```
s = '71B46>TC>77'
modified = ''.join(filter(str.isalnum, s))
# or
modified = ''.join((c for c in s if c.isalnum()))
```

Answer (score 0):

One-Liner-Solution

```
import re
get_chars_before_spl_chars = lambda string1 :re.findall("[\dA-Za-z]*",string1)[0]
get_chars_before_spl_chars('71B46>TC>77')
#'71B46'
```